# Simple reversible encrypt class for strings

Tags: php, cakephp

I use the following class in my CakePHP app to create reversible encrypted ids:

```
class Tiny
{
    public static $set = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    public static function toTiny($id)
    {
        $set = self::$set;

        $HexN="";
        $id = floor(abs(intval($id)));
        $radix = strlen($set);
        while (true)
        {
            $R=$id%$radix;
            $HexN = $set{$R}.$HexN;
            $id=($id-$R)/$radix;
            if ($id==0) break;
        }
        return $HexN;
    }

    public static function reverseTiny($str)
    {
        $set = self::$set;
        $radix = strlen($set);
        $strlen = strlen($str);
        $N = 0;
        for($i=0;$i<$strlen;$i++)
        {
            $N += strpos($set,$str{$i})*pow($radix,($strlen-$i-1));
        }
        return "{$N}";
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something just as simple for strings. Where it has a simple set variable and just two functions, one for encrypting and one for decrypting. All of the ones I have seen so far have been over-complicated and too framework-based. I want a class that is **completely stand-alone and not reliant on other files** and easily integrated into CakePHP.

Can anyone help? Does anyone know of one or could help me modify this script to work with strings instead so I can create another class. It needs to be simple to use: e.g. `Class::encrypt(string);`

Also security is not a major concern here as it's not being used for protecting anything rather just hashing a string in a way that can be reversed.

This is what I want:

```
class Encrypt
{
    public static $set = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    public static function Encrypt($string)
    {
        $set = self::$set;
        return;
    }
    public static function Decrypt($string)
    {
        $set = self::$set;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: By "not reliant on other files", would relying on the mcrypt extension be too much?

Comment: Yes! It needs to be just 1 file! and just two functions!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a modified version of the code that I use. It relies on openssl, so it may not be suitable if you need it to be portable.

```
<?php

class Cipher {                                                                          
   public static function strongRand($num_bytes, $raw = false) {                        
      $rand = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($num_bytes);                                  
      if (!$raw) {                                                                      
         $rand = base64_encode($rand);                                                  
      }
      return $rand;
   }

   public static function encrypt($data, $password = "default", $type = "aes128") {     
      $iv = Cipher::strongRand(12);                                                     
      $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $type, $password, false, $iv);                
      return $iv . $encrypted;                                                          
   }      

   public static function decrypt($data, $password = "default", $type = "aes128") {     
      $iv = substr($data, 0, 16);
      $data = substr($data, 16);                                                        
      $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, $type, $password, false, $iv);                
      return $decrypted;
   }   
}

?>
```

An example of how to use the code:

```
<?php

include('cipher.php');

$enc = Cipher::encrypt('kachow');
echo $enc . "\n";

$dec = Cipher::decrypt($enc);
echo $dec . "\n";

?>
```

Outputs:

```
0fykYiBPJAL/C3fFuX+jApFRdRw7NY8uYmGaaQ==
kachow
```

Comment: Is it possible to get something more similar to Tiny that doesn't rely on anything? And I can specify the set!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to crypt numbers, I use those simple functions (change the random letters in function _map_key to whatever you want, just be sure that they are unique).  If you do not have numbers but string, you can STR2BIN them, then use this function:

```
function _map_kid($kid, $umap=false){
    $map = array('M','Y','S','I','M','P','L','E','K');
    $ret = '';
    for($i = 0; $i<strlen($kid); $i++){
        if($umap){
            $ret .= array_search(substr($kid,$i,1),$map);
        } else {
            $ret .= $map[substr($kid,$i,1)];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
function cript_customer_id($customer_id, $key=0){
    if($key==0){
        $key = trim(microtime(true));
    }
    $key = intval($key);
    if(strlen($key)<=3)     $key +=999;
    if(substr($key,-1)==0)  $key +=3;
    $key = substr($key,-3);
    $kid = ((($customer_id.substr($key,0,1))+substr($key,1,1))*substr($key,-1)).$key;
    return _map_kid($kid);
}

function _decript_customer_id($kid){
    if(trim($kid)=='') return false;
    $kid = strtoupper($kid);
    $kid = _qsc2_map_kid($kid, true);
    $key = substr($kid, -3);
    $customer_id = substr($kid, 0, -3);
    if(substr($key,-1)>0){
        $customer_id = substr((($customer_id/substr($key,-1))-substr($key,1,1)),0,-1);
    } else {
        $customer_id = 0;
    }
    return $customer_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various pure PHP implementations of standard crypto primitives like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) that you could use, like [this](http://www.phpaes.com/) or [this one](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes-php.html).

The [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) algorithm, in particular, is something you could implement in about a dozen lines of PHP if you wanted.

However, those implementations are not likely to be very efficient; in general, when it comes to crypto in high-level languages like PHP, you can have any two out of "secure", "fast" and "self-contained".

---

OK, if all you want is obfuscation, here's something based on [this example](http://php.net/str-rot13#93385) by "peter at NOSPAM jamit dot com" over at php.net:

```
class Obfuscate
{
    public static function obfuscate($string)
    {
        return str_rot13( base64_encode( $string ) );
    }
    public static function deobfuscate($string)
    {
        return base64_decode( str_rot13( $string ) );
    }
}
```

This should be fast and self-contained, but it provides very little security.  At best it makes a nice little puzzle for amateur cryptographers, of a level perhaps comparable with a newspaper crossword puzzle.

Comment: I'm just looking for something very simple takes a strings makes it into a garbled string that I can reverse very easily. The class should be dead simple and just have two functions. And not rely on anything but itself!

Comment: Should those functions also take in a key?  If not, anyone who has seen your code (or guessed how it works) would be able to decrypt the output.  If that's OK with you, I suppose you could always try [`str_rot13()`](http://php.net/str-rot13)...

Comment: I'm not looking for security. Same as the tiny class. It's just a case of making a string messy and usable as code. But that function would not work as it keeps the spaces. It needs to be a proper hash that can be used in a url.

Comment: OK then, how about [this solution](http://php.net/str-rot13#93385) (`$obf = str_rot13(base64_encode($str))`)?  If you're only interested in obfuscation, it should do just fine.

Comment: How would I make a class that can encrypt and decrypt based on a given sent using that then?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [MCrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) functions. It'll be even shorter than the above code. And secure too!

Comment: It needs to be simple and NOT reliant on extensions or other classes.

Comment: It's a part of PHP, just like your `strlen()` and other functions.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use mcrypt, but if don't wanna, the try to find something useful on phpclasses.org, -like this http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2995-PHP-Encode-and-decode-text-strings-with-random-keys.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the link but all the classes I have seen on there are very complex and have many more functions than what I am wanting! I only want two functions and a simple set variable.

Comment: if it ok, if it will be really simple, then just make an array map with letters mapping, like `$arrayMap = array( 'a'=>'l','b'=>a, ... )` and just make some simple loop `for($i=0, $x=count($str)-1; $i<=$x) { $strnew .= $arrayMap[$str[$i] }`

Comment: Could you show an example of how to create a simple Class using what you just said? I really don't know PHP well enough.